# ColorChooser in ComboBox

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, combobox

I would like to have a JColorChooser as items in a ComboBox, such from this example

[image]

This link 
[enter link description here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/ComboBoxcolorchooserWindowsColorChooser.htm)

is the only one I have found about this task, but it is not clear to me

Is there anyone willing to enlight me about how to accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This has some good information that I would recommend reading about the topic. [Color Choosers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/colorchooser.html)

The thing you linked was about using SwingX a 3rd party library that extends Swing. I tried to find the JXComboBox documentation but was only able to find this [JXComboBox](http://swingx.java.net/documentation/#JXComboBox)

That is what that article links to you can find the external Jar [here.](http://java.net/projects/swingx/downloads/directory/releases) Personally I  have used SwingX in the past and always found it to do a fantastic job. I usually use JXDatePicker for a Calendar pop-up.

Update:

I also found the documentation for that class. Found [Here](http://download.java.net/javadesktop/swinglabs/releases/0.8/docs/api/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXComboBox.html)

Also doing some more digging this is possibly more what they are talking about. It's hard for me to find any more information as SwingX website looks like its down

[JXColorSelectionButton](http://www.abusingjava.net/AbusingSwing/doc/SwingX-1.6.3/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXColorSelectionButton.html)

Comment: +1 for the kind words on SwingX, thanks :-) For your information: swinglabs.org is ... broken since ages (nothing we can do about it), the project website is http://swingx.java.net, the latest release 1.6.3 is available via maven.java.net, the current JXComboBox _is not_ the JXComboBox of the early life of SwingX (the latter is still available in the jdnc incubator)